# Select Sum with same ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is a order_table

```
order_id    name            address     telp_num       pay

1         Mamen Suramen    Indonesia     0888888       1.250
2         Edi              Indonesia     0888888       300
```

I have detail of order and I add to query named 'q1',
this is the column

```
|order_id|destination  |    car_id | driver |   date   |sub_total| 

    1        b1           D1000A       sp1      jd1       225
    1        b3           D1000A       sp1      jd2       225
    1        b1           D1000A       sp2      jd1       375
    1        b1           D1000B       sp2      jd3       300
    2        b1           D1000A       sp2      jd3       225
```

I want the result of total where `q1.order_id` like `order_table.order_id`
maybe like this,

```
order id|total|

1        1125
2        225
```

thanks for the answer

Comment: Although I agree with Mitch, +1 for making an effort in the layout of the question. At least the question reads clearly!

Answer (score 2):

```
select q1.order_id,SUM(q2.sub_total)
from order q1 join order_detail q2
on q1.order_id=q2.order_id
group by q1.order_id
```